# XSLT - non-referenced namespaces still propagate when using copy-namespaces="no"

Tags: xslt, namespaces, marklogic

Why doesn't copy-namespaces="no" remove a namespace declaration that's not referenced in the XSLT's output document? I'm using the MarkLogic 5 XSLT processor.

#### Sample input

```
<root xmlns:temp="http://temp" xmlns:keep="http://keep">
  <wrapper><temp:x>A</temp:x>BC<temp:x>D</temp:x></wrapper>
  <keep:me>XYZ</keep:me>
</root>
```

#### Sample XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:temp="http://temp"
  xmlns:keep="http://keep"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" priority="-1" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="temp:x">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Expected output

```
<root xmlns:keep="http://keep">
  <wrapper>ABCD</wrapper>
  <keep:me>XYZ</keep:me>
</root>
```

#### Actual output

```
<root xmlns:temp="http://temp" xmlns:keep="http://keep">
  <wrapper>ABCD</wrapper>
  <keep:me>XYZ</keep:me>
</root>
```

Comment: The provided output cannot be produced from the providedinput using just an identity rule. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: wst, Even though the question is edited, it is still in the same contradictory state -- running the provided transformation on the provided XML document *doesn't* produce the provided result...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev updated and tested.

Comment: wst, Are you joking? Your source XML isn't well-formed -- any test will raise this into an error.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I think you mean it was missing a namespace declaration. It was already well-formed.

Comment: wst, Yes, this is called "namespace - well-formedness" -- an XML parser throws an error on non-well-formed XML strings.

Comment: wst, your "workaround" also doesn't do what you say it is doing -- it doesn't produce your stated wanted result. See my answer for a transformation that really produces this result.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Right, but you only said the XML wasn't well-formed, which is confusing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16734/discussion-between-wst-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirmed with MarkLogic support that this is a bug, and they are working on a fix.

In the meantime, I am using these templates in place of the identity template as a workaround:

```
<xsl:template match="*" priority="-1" mode="#all">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" priority="-1" mode="#all">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" priority="-1" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```